# Number of lattice paths such that all sub-paths of length $k$ are ballot paths.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I'm interested in the problem where I'm counting paths of $a$ up-steps and $b$ down-steps such that for any sub-path of length $s$, there are at least $k$ more up-steps than down-steps.

In other words, let $\#_U$ and $\#_D$ be functions which count the number of up and down-steps in a sequence. Given $a$ up-steps and $b$ down-steps, how many paths $P=p_1,p_2,...,p_{a+b}$ are there such that

$$
\#_U(p_i,p_{i+1},...,p_{i+s-1}) \geq  \#_D(p_i,p_{i+1},...,p_{i+s-1}) + k\;\;\;\forall i \;\;1\leq i \leq a+b - s + 1
$$

Upper and lower bounds in lieu of an exact count would also be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, k ≤ s or the answer is 0.

If s = 1, then whether k is 0 or 1, the path must go up every step, so the answer is 1 iff b = 0.

If s = 2, if k is 1 or 2, the answer is 1 iff b = 0.

Solving s = 2, k = 0 requires a complicated recurrence.